# How to get position from top relative to the device screen?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a sidebar with b-list-group-item(bootstrap4). I want to get the position from top of each item what I clicked.

I tried to get the position by document.getElementbyID but it doesn't helped.

MainPage.vue

scripts:

```
toShow(e){
        if(this.isShown){
          this.isShown = false;
        }
        else{
          this.isShown = true;
          // this.top = document.getElementsByClassName('subCategory').style.top;
          // let heightSubcat = document.getElementsByTagName('b-list-group-item').height;
          // alert(heightSubcat);
          // this.top = heightSubcat - e.clientY + 'px';
          alert(window.scrollY + document.querySelector('div').getBoundingClientRect().top);
        }
      }
    }
```

template:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="mobileMenu" :class="[isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed']">
      <b-list-group>
        <b-list-group-item><span>ФИЗ.ЛИЦАМ</span></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>НАЛОГИ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>ШТРАФЫ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><span>ЮР.ЛИЦАМ</span></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>НАЛОГИ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>ШТРАФЫ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>СОЦИАЛЬНЫЕ ОТЧИСЛЕНИЯ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><span>ИП.КХ</span></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>НАЛОГИ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>ШТРАФЫ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>СОЦИАЛЬНЫЕ ОТЧИСЛЕНИЯ</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><span>ЕД.СОВОКУПНЫЙ ПЛАТЕЖ</span></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>ЕСП (1 МРП)</a></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item @click="toShow" class="subCategory"><a>ЕСП (0.5 МРП)</a></b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the target of the click event:

```
toShow(e){
    if(this.isShown){
      this.isShown = false;
    }
    else{
      this.isShown = true;
      alert(window.scrollY + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! It helped me!